# What is the benefit of untyped variable over an object? What is the difference between null and undefined?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

According to this : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9f.html Quote:

> An untyped variable is not the same as a variable of type Object. The key difference is that untyped variables can hold the special value undefined , while a variable of type Object cannot hold that value.

However when I test it as :

```
            var objTest:Object = 123;           
            var untypedTest:* = 123;

            objTest = undefined;
            untypedTest = undefined;            
            //This is understandable but why was the assignment even allowed?
            trace(objTest); // prints null
            trace(untypedTest); // prints undefined

            objTest=null;
            untypedTest = null;         
            //This is also understandable ... both can store null 
            trace(objTest); // prints null 
            trace(untypedTest); // prints null 

            //If they are null whey are they being equal to undefined? 
            if(objTest==undefined)
                trace("obj is undefined");
            if(untypedTest==undefined)
                trace("untyped is undefined");
            //Because null is same as undefined!
            if(null==undefined)
                trace("null is same as undefined?");
```

Two questions:

- Why is assignment to undefined allowed for obj? (not a big issue since it still prints as null)
- If we compare null with undefined the result true (even if null stored in an Object). What is the point of making a difference between null and undefined if they are equal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Flash has type conversion to convert some types.

Some samples of that:

```
var i:int = NaN;
trace (i); // 0
```

Or:

```
var b:Boolean = null;
trace(b); // false
```

So when you're assigning `undefined` to `Object` instance Flash converts it to `null` the same way.

- Your comparison applied type conversion on incompatible types before evaluating `Boolean`.

You can use strict comparison to have `false`:

```
if(null === undefined)
    trace("Never traced: null is not the same as undefined!");
```

Comment: Awesome ... perfect explanation

Comment: you also use undefined to check to see if a key is in an object. i.e. `if( myObj["someKey"] == undefined ) // add it`. You *could* also use null for the check, but it would break when someone wanted to store null as a value, e.g. `myObj["someKey"] = null; // valid`

Comment: @divillysausages, using `undefined` is deprecated.  It should only be null to prevent confusion.  If you need to store a key with 'no value' just use `0` or `false` (what would be the point of a key with no value anyways?).

Comment: @J_A_X can you point me to a link where it says `undefined` is deprecated? I've used the ability to store `null` under a valid key a number of times. I'd argue against using `0` or `false` as that changes the symantic meaning of what the value is meant to be. (i.e. `null` = an object, `false` = boolean...)

Comment: @divillysausages, look at some of the [compiler warnings](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/compilerWarnings.html) given because of undefined.  undefined was part of ECMAScript, but as AS and Flash move away from it, it has little to no use.  Plus, I would stay clear of anything that can cause me compilation errors for no reason, which is why null is a better standard.

Comment: @J_A_X I'll give you that `undefined` was used more in AS2, but nothing on that page means that it's deprecated. Even the third warning in says "..Only untyped variables (or variables of type *) can be undefined", which indicates that it's still valid (vars stored under keys in objects are *)

Comment: @J_A_X A good definition of the two is "Null is when a variable has been declared but does not have any value. If a variable has not been declared then it is undefined.", which is what we're trying to do to determine if a key is used on an object ( `if myObj["myKey"] == undefined ) // do something`

Comment: I didn't think you could assign NaN? I thought you had to do `i = Number.NaN;`

Answer (score 0):

Some values get silently converted for comparison or assignment.

One such conversion is that of `undefined` being converted to `null` when promoted to `Object`. Hence `null == undefined` because what's basically been done is actually `Object(null) == Object(undefined)` and that is `null == null`.

However, if you do a strict comparison, they are not converted and thus not equal, i.e. `null === undefined` will yield false.